# Probability question with sum

Tags: probability, random-variables

Stuck on a homework problem and I'm not really sure where to start:

Let $X,Y$ be random variables with values in in some finite set $A$ where $P(X = a) = p(a)$, and $P(Y = a) = q(a)$. Let $d = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{a \in A} |p(a) - q(a)|$. Show that $P(X \neq Y) \geq d$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $P(X \neq Y)=1- \sum_{a \in A}p(a)q(a)= 1- \sum_{a \in A''}p(a)q(a)- \sum_{a \in A'}p(a)q(a)$, where $A'=\{ a \in \Omega : p(a)\ge q(a)\}$ and $ \,A'' =\{a \in \Omega : p(a)<q(a)\}$. Then because $q(a) \le 1, \forall a \in A $ and $p(a) \le 1, \forall a \in A $ we can write:
$1- \sum_{a \in A''}p(a)q(a)- \sum_{a \in A'}p(a)q(a) \ge 1- \sum_{a \in A''}p(a)- \sum_{a \in A'}q(a)=\sum_{a \in A} p(a) - \sum_{a \in A''}p(a)- \sum_{a \in A'}q(a)= \sum_{a \in A'}p(a)- \sum_{a \in A'}q(a)=\sum_{a \in A'}p(a)-q(a)=\sum_{a \in A'}|p(a)-q(a)|.$ If instead of write $1$ in term of $p$ we write it in term of $q$ we get:
$1- \sum_{a \in A''}p(a)- \sum_{a \in A'}q(a)=\sum_{a \in A} q(a) - \sum_{a \in A''}p(a)- \sum_{a \in A'}q(a)=\sum_{a \in A''}|q(a)-p(a)|.$ So we have:

$ \frac {1}{2} P(X \neq Y) \ge \frac{1}{2} \sum_{a \in A'}|p(a)-q(a)| $ and 
$\frac {1}{2} P(X \neq Y) \ge \frac{1}{2} \sum_{a \in A''}|q(a)-p(a)|$, summing we obtain:
$P(X \neq Y) \ge \frac{1}{2} \sum_{a \in A}|p(a)-q(a)|$.